# Given: $y'+\frac{1}{2}y =2\cos t, \ y(0) = -1$ to find the coordinates of the first local maximum point $t>0$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

$y'+\frac{1}{2}y =2\cos t, y(0) = -1$

I successfully found the particular solution for the given ODE:
$y(t) = \frac{1}{5}(8\sin(t)+4\cos(t) -9e^{\frac{-t}{2}})$

then, I took the first derivative with respect to t

$y'(t) = \frac{1}{5}(8\cos(t)-4\sin(t) -\frac{9}{2}e^{\frac{-t}{2}})$

Setting y'(t)= 0, I get $(8\cos(t)-4\sin(t) -\frac{9}{2}e^{\frac{-t}{2}})=0$

However, I am stuck at this step and do not know how to proceed further. I cannot solve the equation I have arrived at. Am I missing something? Is there a simpler way to approach this problem?

**EDIT**
i gave up looking for an algebraically solution. Using a computer, I calculated t = 1.364311... (and this is the first root of the equation)  gives $y'(t) = 0$ and $y''(t) = -2.62019...< 0$ thus we indeed get a maximum at that point.

Could someone tell me if my computations are correct?

Comment: What is $cost$?

Comment: Please avoid writing $1/2y$. Does it mean $1/(2y)$ or $(1/2)y$? I guess $(1/2)y$. If so, one error is that you want $e^{-t/2}$ and not $e^{t/2}$ in your solution.

Comment: @mickep: I would ordinarily assume that $1/2y$ means $\frac{1}{2y}$ and not have any objection to that notation, but it looks like the poster intended $\frac{1}{2}y$ instead. For that, $(1/2)y$ is definitely better notation.

Comment: Now the functions are correct. I think you have to use numerical methods to find the value of $t$ where the first positive local maxima is. (@anomaly, I try to avoid to write $1/2y$, but I would also mean $\frac{1}{2y}$.)

Comment: @mickep We haven't covered numerical methods in our class yet, so shouldn't there be another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I thought I found the answer because you miscalculated in your derivation. there should be a + before the exp-function.... but when I corrected it, I got 0=0 ... therefor not a solution.

After rethinking a little bit I got to the solution that it is propably not possible to solve this algebraicly .... so I would try it numericaly... if you have to proove you found the first maxima you could use the  banach fixed - point theorem in [0,2] to find the maximum and proove that it is one and the first.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am having trouble following your solution. Could you explain a little bit more.