# Finding local maximum of solution of a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, maxima-minima

The problem is this:

> Given the differential equation
>   $$y' + \frac{1}{2}y = 2\cos t, y(0)=-1$$
>   Find the coordinates of the first local maximum for the solution when $t>0$

I'm not sure, how to proceed here. I have found the solution given the initial condition which is

$$y(t) = \frac{1}{5}(-9e^{-t/2} + 8 \sin t + 4 \cos t)$$

and from my calculus courses I remember that you have to set $y'(t)=0$ to find the critical points, so I did and got

$$y'(t)=0 \Rightarrow \frac{9}{2}e^{-t/2} + 8 \cos t - 4 \sin t = 0$$

This seems to suggest an infinite number of local maxima and minima for $t>0$, which I corroborated by looking at a graph of the function.

[image]

Using wolfram I found that the first local maximum is at $t\approx 1.36431,$ but I haven't had a course on numerical apporximation, so my question is:

> Is there an analytic method for finding this local maximum?

I appreciate any help!

**Note:** There is an identical question here:[Given: $y'+\frac{1}{2}y =2\cos t, \ y(0) = -1$ to find the coordinates of the first local maximum point $t>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471934/given-y-frac12y-2-cos-t-y0-1-to-find-the-coordinates-of-the-fi) but it never got answered so I hope this one doesn't get closed. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you haven't plotted your solution to the ODE when looking at the title of the graph. In any case, I think calculating the roots analytically might be a hopeless task.

Comment: I went easy on the might; it most certainly is futile. Since you have a graph, you could use Newton's method provided you feed in a good initial guess near the root you want to compute.

Comment: @garserdt216 thanks! I guess I'll have to start iterating then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspect, using numerical methods will solve the problem easily but we shall not use any of them and we shall try to **approximate** the solution of the transcendental equation which, by definition, cannot show any analytical expression.

Considering the first derivative
$$y'(t)= \frac{9}{2}e^{-t/2} + 8 \cos(t) - 4 \sin( t) $$ and using your observation from the plot, let us consider Taylor series built around $t=a$. They are $$e^x=e^{-a}-e^{-a} (x-a)+\frac{1}{2} e^{-a} (x-a)^2+O\left((x-a)^3\right)$$ $$\sin (x)=\sin (a)+(x-a) \cos (a)-\frac{1}{2} (x-a)^2 \sin (a)+O\left((x-a)^3\right)$$
$$\cos(x)=\cos (a)-(x-a) \sin (a)-\frac{1}{2} (x-a)^2 \cos (a)+O\left((x-a)^3\right)$$ Applying them (using for simplicity $a=\frac \pi 2$), we then have 
$$y'(t)=\left(\frac{9 e^{-\pi /4}}{10}-\frac{4}{5}\right)-\left(\frac{8}{5}+\frac{9
   e^{-\pi /4}}{20}\right) \left(t-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{5}+\frac{9
   e^{-\pi /4}}{80}\right) \left(t-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^2+O\left(\left(t-\frac{\pi
   }{2}\right)^3\right)$$ which then reduces to a quadratic equation in $\left(t-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$.

Using the classical formula, we then arrive to $$y'(t)=0 \implies t=\frac{\pi }{2}+\frac{2 \left(9+32 e^{\pi /4}-\sqrt{3 \left(-27+48 e^{\pi /4}+512 e^{\pi
   /2}\right)}\right)}{9+32 e^{\pi /4}}\approx 1.36548$$ while the exact solution would be $t\approx 1.36431$ which seems to be quite good.

Using the result of the approximation, the maximum would be $\approx 0.820081$ while the exact solution would be $\approx 0.820082$.

**Edit**

We could have done better using $a=\frac{5 \pi }{12}$ (we know the values of the trigonometric functions for this angle). Doing the same as above, we should have

$$y'(t)=\left(-3 \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}+\frac{9}{2} e^{-5 \pi /24}\right)-\left(\sqrt{2}+3
   \sqrt{6}+\frac{9}{4} e^{-5 \pi /24}\right) \left(t-\frac{5 \pi
   }{12}\right)+\left(\sqrt{6-3 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{9}{16} e^{-5 \pi /24}\right)
   \left(t-\frac{5 \pi }{12}\right)^2+O\left(\left(t-\frac{5 \pi
   }{12}\right)^3\right)$$ Ignoring the quadratic term, the zero would be given as $t\approx 1.36392$. Using the quadratic term, $t\approx 1.36429$.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for your answer, I didn't even think to use the Taylor series

Comment: @LuisVera. YOu arre welcome ! May I confess that my passion for Taylor series started 60 years ago and that it is more and more intense. Being serious : approximation of functions (Taylor, Padé,..) is a big key for most problems. Just think about it : what is Newton method ? What is Halley's ? What is Householder's ? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer was using Taylor series to approximate locally the function $y'(t)$.

We could also use [Padé approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) which are ratios of polynomials of different degrees of the form $$f(x)=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^m a_i (x-x_0)^i}{1+\sum_{i=1}^n b_i (x-x_0)^i}$$ the coefficients being defined from the successive derivatives of the function evaluated at point $x=x_0$.

To simplify the calculations here, we shall use $x_0=0$ (which extremely simplify the value of the different terms), $m=1$ (to just solve a linear equation) and vary $n$; this will make the solution to be $t=-\frac{a_0}{a_1}$.

The table below reproduces for $y'(t)=0$ the exact results and their decimal representation as well as the value of $y(t)$ as a function of $n$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & t_n & & y(t_n)\\
0 & 2 & 2.00000 & 0.459775 \\
 1 & \frac{20}{21} & 0.95238 & 0.649412 \\
 2 & \frac{126}{85} & 1.48235 & 0.806614 \\
 3 & \frac{200}{153} & 1.30719 & 0.816871 \\
 4 & \frac{5202}{3797} & 1.37003 & 0.820050 \\
 5 & \frac{75940}{55651} & 1.36458 & 0.820082 \\
 6 & \frac{333906}{245327} & 1.36107 & 0.820072 \\
 7 & \frac{137383120}{100565709} & 1.36610 & 0.820079 \\
 8 & \frac{1810182762}{1327776461} & 1.36332 & 0.820081 \\
 9 & \frac{26555529220}{19459260621} & 1.36467 & 0.820082 \\
 10 & \frac{428103733662}{313814366413} & 1.36419 & 0.820082
\end{array}
\right)$$